# Handlebars pagination adding custom links

Tags: javascript, pagination, handlebars.js

Hey so I am using handlebars pagination https://github.com/olalonde/handlebars-paginate

for my back end I am configuring it like that

```
pagination: {
                    page: page,
                    pageCount: pages.length,
                    active: true,
                    category:currentCategory
                  }
```

and on the front end I am reading it like that:

```
  <div class="paginator">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        {{#paginate pagination type="first"}}
                        <li class="page-item{{#if disabled}} disabled{{/if}}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/blog/category/{{{pagination.category}}}/{{n}}" aria-label="First">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">First</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{/paginate}}


                        {{#paginate pagination type="previous"}}
                        <li class="page-item{{#if disabled}} disabled{{/if}}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/blog/category/all/{{n}}" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{/paginate}}
                        <!--{{#paginate pagination type="middle" limit="6"}}-->
                        <!--<li class="page-item">-->
                            <!--<a class="page-link{{#if disabled}} disabled{{/if}}"-->
                               <!--href="/blog/category/all/{{n}}">{{n}}</a>-->
                        <!--</li>-->
                        <!--{{/paginate}}-->
                        {{#paginate pagination type="middle" limit="7"}}
                        <li {{#if active}}class="active" {{/if}}> <a class="page-link" href="/blog/category/all/{{n}}">{{n}}</a>
                        </li>
                        {{/paginate}}
                        {{#paginate pagination type="next"}}
                        <li class="page-item{{#if disabled}} disabled{{/if}}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/blog/category/all/{{n}}" aria-label="Next">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{/paginate}}
                        {{#paginate pagination type="last"}}
                        <li class="page-item{{#if disabled}} disabled{{/if}}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/blog/category/all/{{n}}" aria-label="Last">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{/paginate}}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my issue is here:

when I try to inject this variable to the url of the pagination it never shows.
I tried to use {{}} and three curly {{{}}} but it never show up.
I also tried to handle it like that on the back end:

```
pagination: {
                    page: page,
                    pageCount: pages.length,
                    active: true,
                  },
                  category:currentCategory
```

and read it but it also don't show up. 
how I can inject this variable to my pagination url ?

Answer (score 0):

so actually in to order to do this I had to create a handlebars helper and then use it.
so this was my helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( "getCategory", function (f){

                    return '/blog/category/'+currentCategory + '/' + f;
                });
```

the (f) is nothing but just to make it work! and get the links right.
and then on the view I used it simple:

```
href="{{getCategory n}}"
```